# Working with z-index and opacity not giving desired result (Image and Text layout)

Tags: html, css, web

I'm a learner in HTML and CSS. I'm trying to put a text with image on its top. My requirement is to be able to hide the image (possibly using `opacity`). The sample that I've picked to imitate (just for my learning purpose) is all the `.dribbble`s here: https://dribbble.com/dte.

CSS/HTML:

```css
#images
{
 border: 0.25em solid red;
 overflow:auto;
 width:30%;
}
#images > figure
{
 margin: 1em;
 float:left;
 width: 80%;
 position: relative;
}
/* #images > figure > a
{
 max-width:30%;
 height: 10%;
} */
#images > figure >  img
{
 /* max-height:50%; */
 /* max-width: 80%; */
 border-radius:25%;
 position: relative;
 max-width:100%;
 z-index: 0;
}
#images > figure > img:hover
{
 z-index: -3;
 opacity:.1;
}
#images > figure > div.hidden
{
 position: absolute; 
 top:0px;
 left: 10px;
 opacity:0;
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
 /* z-index: -0; */
 /* overflow:hidden; */ 
}
#images > figure > div.hidden:hover
{
 opacity:1;
 /* height:100%; */
 /* z-index: -1; */
}
```

```html
<section id="images">
 <figure>
  <img
   alt="first"
   src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3221/2658147888_826edc8465.jpg"
  >
  <div class="hidden"> 
   <span> Howdy <br />
   </span>
  </div>
 </figure>
</section>
```

My not-working-code can be found here as well: http://jsfiddle.net/5RJTc/

Please guide me as to what I'm missing out here or what I'm doing wrong here so that I can learn how to make such good stuff.

Comment: Your text is appearing. Just give it a background so it masks the image (last rule, add `background-color: pink`) http://jsfiddle.net/5RJTc/2/

Comment: @FelipeAls: If you notice the URL that I've given in the question: https://dribbble.com/dte, the image becomes transparent and text appears from behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/roberttang30/5RJTc/4/

CSS/HTML:

```css
#images {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 133px;
    text-align: center;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
}
.images {
    height: 100%;
    /*The following lines simply add the fade out effect and are optinal*/
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s; 
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s; 
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s; 
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.hidden {
    z-index: -1;    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.images:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
    <img alt="first" id="1" class="images" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3221/2658147888_826edc8465.jpg"> 
    <div class="hidden"> Howdy </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be great if you could briefly explain the mistake I was doing as it would help me in future

Comment: Ok. I got it. I was doing some over-work which was not required (e.g. I was trying to bring text to the top using `z-index` when it is already there. And, I had given `opacity: 0` to the text initially and was trying to make it opaque (`opacity: 1`), which was not really required. The only thing required was to send the image to the background using `z-index: -1` and make it transparent. Thanks for the solution

Comment: The problem you were having was that the image was always visible and you were only making the text visible which just meant that they were now both visible. What you had to do to solve this was to hide the image. I did this by setting the images opacity to 0 when it was not wanted and having both elements visible normally but the text behind the image so that it could not be seen. I also changed the general structure a bit to make it simpler/easier to understand but this was not necessary. If I have not explained this properly please say.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your second comment before I posted mine. You are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Stackoverflow rocks !